# Please translate 他听到我们这边有水瓶掉下去 砰地一声 （正好是停车场出口 万一有车就很危险）他马上和保安指出来 小朋友好乖哦

Tags: translation

他听到我们这边有水瓶掉下去 砰地一声
（正好是停车场出口 万一有车就很危险）他马上和保安指出来 小朋友好乖哦

He heard bottle fell down ( ;$*#*#? (I can't trans it)
He and bodyguard pointed out??

Comment: ？？？But the Chinese text is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to do a word-to-word translation. The original text seems like a piece of transcripts of someone talking.

In the parenthesis, where you can't translate, it is to describe where the accident happened - it is right at the exit of the parking garage. It can be very dangerous if there is a car drive by

他马上和保安指出来 is "he immediately told(or point it out to) the security guard". 和 is not "and" here, but "to".

小朋友好乖哦 tells me that in the previous description, 他 is a 小朋友. This sentence is opinion from the person who told this story.

Comment: Oh thank you so much yes 小朋友=他

Answer (score 1):

他听到砰地一声 我们这边有水瓶掉下去
他听到“砰”的一声，原来是我们这边有水瓶掉在了地上，摔碎了。
He just heard the crash of our water bottle smashing on the ground,

(正好是停车场出口 万一有车就很危险）
正好是在停车场出口，万一有车从碎玻璃上经过，会很危险。
(it was just in the car park exit, if there had been any cars, it could have been dangerous)

他马上和保安指出来 小朋友好乖哦
他立即告诉保安停车场出口有碎玻璃。这真是一个很乖的小朋友。
He immediately told the guard. What a well behaved child!

Comment: Oh thank you so much       finally, I can understand it clearly 